# Is it possible to send the equivalent of an ALT+F4 to a windowed Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, function-keys

I'm already aware that you can send all the following, but how do I send an ALT F4?

```
CTRL+ALT+END        CTRL ALT DEL
ALT+PAGE UP         ALT TAB (more or less)
ALT+PAGE DOWN       ALT SHIFT TAB (more or less)
ALT+INSERT          Cycle through windows
ALT+HOME            Win Key
ALT+DELETE          Context menu/right click button
CTRL+ALT+Minus      ALT+PRINT SCREEN
CTRL+ALT+Plus       PRINT SCREEN
```

Comment: well... I just pressed alt/F4, tadaah. Maybe something [media kyes etc] is getting in the way?

Comment: @Tetsujin In windowed mode. All keyboard shortcuts work as standard when fullscreen by default, (try the others) but this prevents you from alt tabbing out of the window.

Comment: This behavior can be enabled in fullscreen mode too, but by default windows keyboard shortcuts are as per usual when fullscreen, and as above in windowed mode.